# wampserver 2 - displays as online but not working

Tags: php, apache, localhost, wampserver

I am trying to work with php on wampserver 2.  When I go to turn the wampserver on, the color of the icon will only go from red to orange (it is supposed to go from red->orange->green).  I can never get the localhost to be displayed.  I tried completely removing wampserver from my computer, restarting my computer, and installing wampserver 2 again.  I'm still getting the same problems.  Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That also happens to me sometime, I got a question to ask you. Do you use Skype? If your Skype is open before running wampserver, you better quit your skype first.

Comment: I do use skype.  This fixed it.  Thanks

Comment: What if the same problem occurs even without having skype running and/or installed?

Answer (score 1):

If u installed other database servers e.g.SQLserver2005 or 2008 first stop that services using administrativetools inthe control panel and start the wampserver apache service from the admin tools.
                    This one really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

And check who is actually using port 80. May be that port is being used by IIS also.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i also faced same the problem many times. I have done following things.You also please try

1) Firstly, Uninstall the wamp server through control panel.

2) After completion of uninstall process, please remove wamp folder from your installation directory(Mostly it is located c drive itself.If your wamp folder is in c drive,Please delete it.). If you didn't remove this folder you may get the problem again.

3) Now restart your computer

4) Install latest version of wamp server.

5) Check whether wamp server is working or not?

6) Still it is not working then change the port number of wamp by visiting the below link

```
   [http://www.invialgo.com/2011/change-wampserver-port/][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

go to wamp server -> apache -> httpd.conf 
open that file
change === #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
             Listen 80
to

## Listen 12.34.56.78:8080

Listen 8080
 then restart services you have done